# Multiple results returning from a HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to display a singular piece of data from a HABTM relationship in my view wrapped in a link_to, but it seems to be returning the same result multiple times and increasing by 1 whenever and I add a post.

> Example
>
> It will return 'Category:Comedy', then when I create another Post
>   with the same category it will return 'Category:Comedy Comedy' and so
>   on.

For the life of me I don't know why this would be happening.

**Category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
    <% post.categories.each do |category| %>
      <% category.posts.each do |post| %>
        <%= link_to category.name, category_path(category) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Any help would be brilliant!

Thanks

Comment: What does your posts#create action look like?

Comment: Added this to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are running two loops for displaying category, so may be removing the inner loop will not repeat the category links.

```
<% post.categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= link_to category.name, category_path(category) %
<% end %>
```